# What is the purpose of the Desktop Switcher?

Tags: launcher, shortcut-keys

What is the real use of Desktop switcher in the Ubuntu?. I have opened a FireFox instance in one desktop. Then I switched to another desktop and tried opening another instance of FireFox. Its not happening because we can have only one instance. Then what is the real use for multiple desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the programs can run multiple instances and it is really useful to work on several desktops when you have many programs running and they are not related to each other (like Gedit and FTP client, if you are web developer and you often edit files and upload them to the web host and other group of programs like Music Player or Libre Office documents).

I often open Firefox in my second workspace to listen YouTube playlist and on the first workspace I have Notepad++, FileZilla and Firefox (if you open Firefox and drag a tab you can have two instances of the browser running)

For most programs, including firefox, you can middle-click the icon in the launcher to open a new instance.

Comment: Notepad++ :o
in wine?

Comment: @AboobackerMk I cannot leave my lovely Notepad++ behind at the times when I was Windows user. I just can't. It is the best tool for web developer for me and I really need it as it is exactly. I cannot use Gedit. I'm really looking forward for the day when there will be a port for Linux.

Comment: @IvanDokov: I understand the love a man can have towards his preferred text editor. I am guilty of this too but Geany is pretty nice if you are used to notepad++. Just make sure you install the plug ins.